# How can I avoid that a key assigned with temporary variable changes later?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I fell I'm missing something very basic here. I'm trying to store values in pgfkeys so I can retrieve them later. However, I have to make use of some calculations and if I reuse macros, all the stored values change as well. Here you have a MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}

--- 1st interation\\
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\tmp{0}
\pgfkeys{/x/.initial=\tmp}
x (pgfkeys): \pgfkeys{/x}\\
x (pgfkeysvalueof): \pgfkeysvalueof{/x}

--- 2nd interation\\
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\tmp{1}
x (pgfkeys): \pgfkeys{/x}\\
x (pgfkeysvalueof): \pgfkeysvalueof{/x}

\end{document}
```

The resultant document is as follows:

```
— 1st interation
x (pgfkeys): 0
x (pgfkeysvalueof): 0
— 2nd interation
x (pgfkeys): 1
x (pgfkeysvalueof): 1
```

As you can see, the value of the pgfkey x changed even if I didn't touch it. I look forward to understand:

- Why the later change in the \tmp var also changes the previous assignment?
- How can I avoid changing values that are previously assigned?

Comment: you defined the key to be the token `\tmp` (not the expansion of that token) so when you access the key you get `\tmp` which if you then use it expands to whatever definition it has at that time. The key value itself has not changed.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCarlisle. It makes sense. I didn't realize that I could use the expansion of the token as pointed out by marmot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about expanding the key such that this does not happen? That way you do not tell the key to have the value of the macro `\tmp` but rather the value `\tmp` expands to at the time you set the key.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}

--- 1st interation\\
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\tmp{0}
\pgfkeys{/x/.initial/.expanded=\tmp}
x (pgfkeys): \pgfkeys{/x}\\
x (pgfkeysvalueof): \pgfkeysvalueof{/x}

--- 2nd interation\\
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\tmp{1}
x (pgfkeys): \pgfkeys{/x}\\
x (pgfkeysvalueof): \pgfkeysvalueof{/x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! That was simple. I've seen the `expanded` handle, but I couldn't understand how to use it. Thanks! I'll give it a try and get back to you =)

Comment: You have no idea how long I spent yesterday looking for a solution for this x). Accepted. =) And I learned that I can have handles of handles. Interesting.

Comment: @tecepe Yes, these things are tricky and one is never done learning them. The pgfmanual spends quite some pages on teaching you how to draw a circle but is a little bit shorter on the pgfkeys, even though they are useful far beyond drawing some things, i.e. what this stuff is mainly being used for.